# Problema con Git Pull, no se completa el merge cuando tengo que eliminar archivos

Tags: git, git-bash, git-pull

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?
Cada vez que en el repositorio eliminan algo, me sale ese mensaje y por mas que le digo que si, no deja de salir, al final cuando corto el comando con CTRL+C el merge queda a medias y es muy pesado de arreglar, siempre me toca coger los archivos que estan ignorados, hacer un respaldo, eliminar toda la carpeta y volver a realizar un git clone del repositorio completo para poder continuar, esto llega a ser molesto porque la carpeta de imagenes pesa casi 500mb y realmente esto no me pasaba antes, todos sus comentarios son bienvenidos, muchas gracias.

Ya intenté desinstalando y volviendo a instalar git pero no funcionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente cuando ejecutas git pull, (1) O no tienes permiso de lectura/escritura sobre esos archivos o (2) Tienes algun otro programa que está accediendo a esos archivos y te está impidiendo borrarlos (esto podría ser algun antivirus o algun otro programa externo)